# Unix shell script how to test all the array values is equal to particular value?

Tags: linux

I Have three array variables like
    var[1]=1
    var[2]=1
    var[3]=1
Now i want to check all these three array variables is equal to 1 or not using if command.

I tried something like

```
if [[ ${var[@] == 1 ]]; then
echo "Yes"
else
echo "No"
fi
```

The result of the above code should be Yes but i'm getting No as an answer.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You are missing `}`. Also, you can't check whole array like that. `${var[@]}` will be `"1 1 1"`, which is not equal to `"1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${var[@]}` will expand to `1 1 1` which is most definitely *not* equal to `1`.

You can use something like:

```
rc=Yes
for val in ${var[@]} ; do
    if [[ ${val} != 1 ]]; then
        rc=No
    fi
done
echo $rc
```

or the more succinct:

```
rc=Yes
for v in ${var[@]}; do [[ $v == 1 ]] || rc=No; done
echo $rc
```